# How to define a VHDL component and package?

Tags: package, components, vhdl

Below I do have following two VHDL files. The file **x.vhd** with a *component* *x* which needs to be referenced (included) in the file **top.vhd** as a package.

```
-- x.vhd

library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;

package x_pkg is
    component my_x
        port(clk_clk          : in  std_logic    := '0';
             reset_reset_n    : in  std_logic    := '0';
    end component my_x;
end package x_pkg;

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;

entity x is
    port (
        clk_clk               : in  std_logic         := '0';             --                             clk.clk        
        reset_reset_n         : in  std_logic         := '0';             --                           reset.reset_n
    );
end entity x;

architecture rtl of x is
```

This package needs to be referenced in following top-file:

```
-- top.vhd

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

library altera;
use altera.altera_syn_attributes.all;
use work.x_pkg.all;

entity EyeTracker_Top is
    port
    (
        Nios_Clk : in std_logic;
        Nios_Reset_n : in std_logic;
    );

end EyeTracker_Top;

architecture struct of EyeTracker_Top is

begin
M1 : my_x port map(Nios_Clk, Nios_Reset_n);            -- Here I get the error message!
```

After compiling, it get following error message:

***Error (12006): Node instance "M1" instantiates undefined entity "my_x"

---

What is the problem here? I guess there is something wrong with the package reference...

Thanks!

Comment: `use x.x_pkg.all;` shall probably be `use Misc.x_pkg.all;` or `use work.x_pkg.all;`. As you are not showing the part of your source code that raised the error, there is not much more we can do for you.

Comment: There was a typo in the library name -> library x;    When I change to `use work.x_pkg.all` then I get the error message: **Error (10481): VHDL Use Clause error at EyeTracker_Top.vhd(23): design library "work" does not contain primary unit "nios_pkg"** Therefore I think ùse x.x_pkg.all`is correct...

Comment: I edited the question please see above!

Comment: You cannot use the same name for too many things. Try, maybe, to use different names for your library, component and entity. Avoid especially to have the same library and component names, it puzzles the parser that hides both declarations.

Comment: I changed the component name (see above to my_x). It seems there is indeed a problem with the names. When I use **library x** is **x** simply my x.vhd file or..? Do I need to add such **library x** to the project libraries too? If so, is it the path to my x.vhd? Sorry, but at the moment it is a bit confusing...

Comment: Entities can not have the same name as their library. They share the same namespace. I personally name all my libraries `L_*` to avoid conflicts.

Comment: ok, but do I need **library x;** in my **top.vhd** file? I would  rather use `use work.x_pkg.all` but then I get the error `design library "work" does not contain primary unit "x_pkg". Why I can not use work here?

Comment: Every VHDL Compilation Unit (entity, architecture...) is compiled in a library. When compiling a CU you specify in which library (`work` by default). If you want to reuse a CU in another design, you must: 1) compile the CU in its library, 2) declare in the top level that you will be using the library. `work` is a special library name. It designates the library in which you are currently compiling. So if you compile in library `foo_lib` and what you compile contains a `use work.x_pkg.all;` statement, then `x_pkg` must have been compiled in `foo_lib` first.

Comment: ok, now I can use the **work** library (see code above). But what (still) does not work is the access to instantiation **M1**. Following error occurs at the line with **M1**: Error (12006): Node instance "M1" instantiates undefined entity "my_x". Is there a wrong instantiation?

Comment: again, which files and which libraries needs to be added to the project?

Comment: You seem to have `x_pkg` and `x` in the same file. Some tools may expect one compilation unit per file, so it may be worth splitting `x_pkg` into its own file.

Comment: Alternatively, short circuit the whole issue and directly instantiate the entity. No componett necessary, and no package either.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Why it is a problem to have `x_pkg`and `x` in the same file? I think this have to be like this when I like to use the package `x_pkg` in my top.vhd file again. I am using quartus web-edition Vers. 15 by the way. If I do the shortcut it may work but I think it is better to use the component definition NOT in the top-file.

Comment: If it works with your tools, that's OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are instantiating a component `my_x`. A component is just a declaration, a kind of empty shell. Every component instantiation must at some point be bound to an actual entity/architecture pair. This binding must be done with an explicit configuration. There are several ways to do this.  One is to add:

```
for all: my_x use work.x(rtl);
```

in the declaration area of your architecture (between `architecture` and `begin`). Of course, the entity `x` and its architecture `rtl` must be compiled in the library you use as `work` before you can elaborate your top level.

The error message you got is difficult to understand because your tool tries to apply a default configuration strategy based on names: for unbound instances of components it searches an entity with the same name as the component. Because it found none, it complains about a missing entity while it is a component binding problem, that is, a missing configuration. A better tool would tell you that the `M1` instance of component `my_x` is not bound.

A last note: if all this component stuff is too complicated for your needs, just get rid of it and directly instantiate your entity:

```
M1: entity work.x(rtl) port map(Nios_Clk, Nios_Reset_n);
```

and you will need no component declaration and no configuration.

There are basically two approaches:

- top-down design with components instantiations and configurations,
- bottom-up design with entity instantiations, no components and no configurations.

Understanding the differences between the two, their pros and cons is not easy. And there, a good VHDL book is probably better than questions and answers on stackoverflow.

Comment: What do you mean with " Of course, the entity x and its architecture rtl must be compiled in the library you use as work before you can elaborate your top level."? How can I do that?

Comment: Ok - direct instantiation is the key of the solution although I do not fully understand why my approach did not work - thanks!

Comment: @Norick _How can I do that?_ You first compile file `x.vhd`, specifying that the target library is let's say, `x_lib`. Then you compile `top.vhd` with the same target library such that, all references to library `work` in `top.vhd` are in fact references to `x_lib`. Then, you can launch your simulation or synthesis.

Comment: +1 for showing me that I could get rid of the component definition completely. I find having to update both component definitions and port mappings every time I change the interface on an entity is very tedious, plus the component definitions are often more than 50% of the total file length.