# Quartus Prime VHDL component instantiation compile error

Tags: vhdl, quartus

I am having an issue when trying to compile the following code:

```
----------------
----------------
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

entity adder_top is
Port ( a_in : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
       b_in : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
       clk : in STD_LOGIC;
       clk_en : in STD_LOGIC;
       carry_in : in STD_LOGIC;
       carry_out : out STD_LOGIC;
       c_out : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0));
end adder_top;

architecture Behavioral of adder_top is
COMPONENT c_addsub_0
  PORT (
    A : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
    B : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
    CLK : IN STD_LOGIC;
    C_IN : IN STD_LOGIC;
    CE : IN STD_LOGIC;
    C_OUT : OUT STD_LOGIC;
    S : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0)
  );
END COMPONENT c_addsub_0;
begin
inst_1 : COMPONENT c_addsub_0
    port map
    (
        A => a_in,
        B => b_in,
        CLK => clk,
        C_IN => carry_in,
        CE => clk_en,
        C_OUT => carry_out,
        S => c_out
    );

end Behavioral;

---------------------------
---------------------------
```

I receive the following error code when trying to compile:

> Error (12006): Node instance "inst_1" instantiates undefined entity
>   "c_addsub_0". Ensure that required library paths are specified
>   correctly, define the specified entity, or change the instantiation.
>   If this entity represents Intel FPGA or third-party IP, generate the
>   synthesis files for the IP.

I am entirely unsure why I am receiving this error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A little [research](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Error+%2812006%29%3A+Node+instance) is in order. If the first question found with an answer ([How to define a VHDL component and package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33007460/how-to-define-a-vhdl-component-and-package)) isn't adequate then your question isn't specific enough.

Answer (score 0):

The synthesis tool (Quartus) used to analyze and elaborate (a.k.a. *compile*) your design is complaining that it has not found an entity to *bind* the component `c_addsub_0` with. You need to point the tool, in a tool defined way, to a library that contains the desired `entity`.

If you intended `c_addsub_0` to be a block that you created then maybe it did not analyze into the `work` library as expected (unexpected syntax errors), or the library path to the `work` library is not established correctly (unlikely for a synthesis tool). If you wrote `c_addsub_0` then it may be easier to use direct entity instantiation -- it saves the hassle of writing the `component` declaration and keep it in sync with the instance and the entity in another file. For example:

```
inst_1 : ENTITY work.c_addsub_0(<arch_name>)
    port map
    (
        A => a_in,
        B => b_in,
        CLK => clk,
        C_IN => carry_in,
        CE => clk_en,
        C_OUT => carry_out,
        S => c_out
    );
```

If the `c_addsub_0` block is meant to be unbound through elaboration, as a *black box* until place-and-route, then you need to tell Quartus by [decorating the instance with the appropriate `syn_black_box` attribute](https://www.altera.com/documentation/jbr1437426657605.html#mwh1409960067652).

```
architecture Behavioral of adder_top is
COMPONENT c_addsub_0
  PORT (
    A : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
    B : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
    CLK : IN STD_LOGIC;
    C_IN : IN STD_LOGIC;
    CE : IN STD_LOGIC;
    C_OUT : OUT STD_LOGIC;
    S : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0)
  );
END COMPONENT c_addsub_0;

attribute syn_black_box : boolean;
attribute syn_black_box of c_addsub_0: component is true;

begin
...
```

It then knows to synthesize a black box representation in the post synthesis netlist for that component. You then need to insure the Quartus back end can find a netlist for the given component in a netlist library path somewhere.

VHDL provides for a variety of ways to create hierarchy with incredibly precise control over binding, signal connections, naming/renaming of blocks and other features which are rarely used in ordinary designs. Unless your synthesis tool only supports one style of instantiation using component declarations or you need a black box, then I would stick with direct entity instantiation.

**P.S.:** Your use clause `use ieee.std_logic_unsigned;` should be `use synopsys.std_logic_unsigned;` -- The IEEE standards body never approved the `std_logic_unsigned` package. Though, if analyzing with the 1076-2008 standard, it is allowed now to analyze anything you want into the `IEEE` library. That permits *defacto* vendor, but not formally standardized, packages to be used without modification of your source code. Only the `STD` library is now actually a *standard*. Just be aware that Mentor Graphics and Synopsys versions of this package are different so your code may not achieve the portability that use of the standards based `numeric_std` package will achieve.

Comment: It's not a VHDL language error to have an unbound component unlike the synthesis tool. It seems unlikely adder_top's only statement is intended to be unbound it's a wrapper to change port formal names. P.S. - There are no restrictions on what can be placed in library IEEE unlike STD (IEEE Std 1076-2008, 13.2). The standard provides numeric_std_unsigned in place of std_logic_unsigned (16.8.5). Regardless, it's not used in adder_top.

Comment: Sounds like the IEEE standards body caved to the Synopsys hijacking of the IEEE library name by explicitly sanctioning their action in 1076-2008. (Thanks for the LRM reference @user1155120.) How funny, but sad really.

Comment: The 2008 revision is the first to incorporate std_logic_1164 and the synthesis libraries previously found in IEEE Std 1164-1993 and IEEE Std 1076.3-1997. Those standards also specifying the various packages be analyzed into library IEEE while specifying no restriction on other content. Consider Synopsys contributed both MVL9 and std_logic_arith to the respective standardization efforts. Your bias is not uncommon but not factually based.